# How to debug a Chrome extension in WebStorm?

Tags: javascript, windows, debugging, google-chrome-extension, webstorm

I loaded a Chrome extension in Chrome using load unpacked in developer mode.
I know how to debug inside Devtools.

How does one develop and debug an extension using WebStorm where WebStorm's breakpoints in the extension's Javascript get hit?

Answer (score 1):

No special support for debugging Chrome extensions is currently provided, see [WEB-9708](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-9708).

The IDE can attach a debugger to a running Chrome instance started with `--remote-debugging-port` option using [Attach to Node.js\Chrome](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2021.3/run-debug-configuration-node-js-remote-debug.html) run configuration; see if it works for you

Comment: If Chrome was launched on port 9222 does WebStorm need to use the same port? if I have multiple instances of Chrome running, how does WebStorm know which instance to connect to?

Comment: You need to specify a port you pass in `--remote-debugging-port` option in the **Attach to Node.js\Chrome** run configuration settings in order to attach the debugger to the Chrome instance